# Access foreign key in LINQ Where?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an entity called Driver and to get a list of Drivers, I call:

```
List<Driver> drivers = _context.Drivers.Select(x=>x);
```

Driver can have details and their is a foreign key between them, but I can't do:

```
List<Driver> drivers = _context.Where(x=>x.id == id && x.Detail.id == detailId);
```

How can I get to my foreign key properties in my Where clause?

I am using `Entity Framework 3.5`.

The statement works, although I am not sure (x=>x) is necessary, I haven't actually compiled it:

```
List<Driver> drivers = _context.Drivers.Select(x=>x);
```

The problem is that the `Driver` entity has a foreign relation to `Detail`, `Driver` has a `DetailId` column which is a foreign key to the Detail table and since I am using Entity Framework 3.5, I can't get to `Driver.Detail.Id` or `Driver.DetailId`. They don't come up.  I did read something about `EF 3.5` not including foreign keys and then having the choice in `EF 4`, but I am on `EF 3.5` for now.

I did try to do `.Include("Detail")`, but it gave me some exception about `Detail not being a navigation property.`

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is it not letting you do? What error does your code give you currently?

Comment: What's wrong with your second Linq statment?

Comment: Can you show your **Driver** class ?

Comment: that's (your 2nd line) actually creating just the right SQL - with EF the most intuitive is usually the right way. You must be having something else that's not working.

Comment: @NSGaga - I added some detail.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that @Xaisoft :). That's quite old, earlier versions were full of things like that. So you did try `DetailId` column (providing it's mapped at all), I'm sorry I have no idea nor ways to check.

Comment: Regarding the `Select(x => x)` your suspicion is correct, it's redundant. `_context.Drivers.ToList()` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Include` method in your case. Ref [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with EF 3.5 but maybe you can tackle it like this:

```
context.drivers.Where(x => x.Detail == 
     context.Details.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == detailId))
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed some of the code.  I added more detail if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `_context.Where()` because `_context` isn't `IQueryable<Driver>`.

Try `_context.Drivers.Where()` instead.

Your best clue is the error message you're getting about `Detail` *not being a navigation property*; try adding one to the `Driver` entity - if it's 1 driver : many details:

```
public virtual ICollection<Detail> Details { get; set; }
```

If it's 1 driver : 1 detail:

```
public virtual Detail Detail { get; set; }
```

In the .dbml you can specify those using an *association*; if you imported your model from an existing db the FK's should have been imported as *associations*, but if they didn't (or if the db doesn't define them) you can always add them manually.

With a navigation property, EF should be able to evaluate something like this:

```
var driversWithDetails = _context.Drivers
                                 .Where(x => x.Id == id && x.Detail.Id == detailId)
                                 .Include (x => x.Detail).ToList();
```

Comment: I think the `public virtual Detail` / `ICollection<Detail>` part only applies to EF 4.1 code-first. For EF 3.5 I believe it's all in the .dbml.